# Creating a decorator in a class with access to the (current) class itself

Tags: python, inheritance, class, decorator

Currently, I'm doing it in this fashion:

```
class Spam(object):

    decorated = None

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, funct):
        if cls.decorated is None:
            cls.decorated = []
        cls.decorated.append(funct)
        return funct


class Eggs(Spam):
    pass


@Eggs.decorate
def foo():
    print "spam and eggs"


print Eggs.decorated # [<function foo at 0x...>]
print Spam.decorated # None
```

I **need** to be able to do this in a subclass as shown. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the `decorated` field not shared between instances. Right now I have a hackish solution by initially setting it to `None` and then checking it when the function is decorated, but that only works one way. In other words, if I subclass `Eggs` and then decorate something with the `Eggs.decorate` function, it affects all subclasses.

I guess my question is: is it possible to have mutable class fields that don't get shared between base and sub classes?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you need to keep track of which functions have been decorated?

Comment: Good question. I actually don't, but I devised this scenario as an example for this question because it is a simple reason one would need to be able to access the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out through using metaclasses. Thanks for all who posted. Here is my solution if anybody comes across a similar problem:

```
class SpamMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        SpamType = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        SpamType.decorated = []
        return SpamType


class Spam(object):

    __metaclass__ = SpamMeta

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, funct):
        cls.decorated.append(funct)
        return funct


class Eggs(Spam):
    pass


@Eggs.decorate
def foo():
    print "spam and eggs"


print Eggs.decorated # [<function foo at 0x...>]
print Spam.decorated # []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you can't.  I thought about doing this with property(), but unfortunately the class of the class itself--where a property would need to go--is ClassType itself.

You can write your decorator like this, but it changes the interface a little:

```
class Spam(object):
    decorated = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_decorated_methods(cls):
        return cls.decorated.setdefault(cls, [])

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, funct):
        cls.get_decorated_methods().append(funct)
        return funct


class Eggs(Spam):
    pass


@Spam.decorate
def foo_and_spam():
    print "spam"

@Eggs.decorate
def foo_and_eggs():
    print "eggs"

print Eggs.get_decorated_methods() # [<function foo_and_eggs at 0x...>]
print Spam.get_decorated_methods() # [<function foo_and_spam at 0x...>]
```

Comment: I got it to work perfectly with using metaclasses. I posted the answer if you're curious as to how. Thanks for investigating, Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have anything against metaclasses, but you can also solve it without them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Spam(object):
    _decorated = defaultdict(list)

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, func):
        cls._decorated[cls].append(func)
        return func

    @classmethod
    def decorated(cls):
        return cls._decorated[cls]


class Eggs(Spam):
    pass

@Eggs.decorate
def foo():
    print "spam and eggs"

print Eggs.decorated() # [<function foo at 0x...>]
print Spam.decorated() # []
```

It is not possible to have properties on class objects (unless you revert to metaclasses again), therefore it is mandatory to get the list of decorated methods via a classmethod again. There is an extra layer of indirection involved compared to the metaclass solution.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be similar to how Glenn did it. Even though it works for this example, it still doesn't solve the issue at hand being that I didn't want class fields shared between parent and child.